# How do I run golint in docker build

Tags: go, docker-build

I have the following in my docker-build file:

```
# Runs lint
RUN go get -u golang.org/x/lint/golint
RUN golint ./...
```

Doing this seems to not work, this is the output I get:

```
 Step 34/38 : RUN go get -u golang.org/x/lint/golint
[01:41:31][Step 2/10]  ---> Running in 23acc6d25de3
[01:41:33][Step 2/10] go: finding golang.org/x/lint latest
[01:41:33][Step 2/10] go: downloading golang.org/x/lint v0.0.0-20210508222113-6edffad5e616
[01:41:33][Step 2/10] go: extracting golang.org/x/lint v0.0.0-20210508222113-6edffad5e616
[01:41:33][Step 2/10] go: downloading golang.org/x/lint v0.0.0-20190313153728-d0100b6bd8b3
[01:41:33][Step 2/10] go: extracting golang.org/x/lint v0.0.0-20190313153728-d0100b6bd8b3
[01:41:33][Step 2/10] go: downloading golang.org/x/tools v0.0.0-20190624222133-a101b041ded4
[01:41:34][Step 2/10] go: extracting golang.org/x/tools v0.0.0-20190624222133-a101b041ded4
[01:41:34][Step 2/10] go: finding golang.org/x/tools v0.1.3
[01:41:35][Step 2/10] go: downloading golang.org/x/tools v0.1.3
[01:41:35][Step 2/10] go: extracting golang.org/x/tools v0.1.3
[01:41:45][Step 2/10] Removing intermediate container 23acc6d25de3
[01:41:45][Step 2/10]  ---> 8bbf3cabfd41
[01:41:45][Step 2/10] Step 35/38 : RUN golint ./...
[01:41:45][Step 2/10]  ---> Running in e3fe5ec9e62e
[01:41:45][Step 2/10] /bin/sh: golint: command not found
```

Comment: What Docker image are you using?

Comment: You need to add `"$GOPATH/bin"` to the `PATH` used in your container.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Jens!  The answer was to either add $GOPATH/bin to path or to just use $GOPATH/bin (which is what I did).  In particular the solution was:

```
# Run lint
RUN go get -u golang.org/x/lint/golint
RUN ${GOPATH}/bin/golint -set_exit_status ./...
```